# Nil Current_user in modified Devise create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created a custom Registration controller for Devise. I inserted a param in my form that says if it's true I should do some extra stuff after registration, for example, create a related company for the user.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :token

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
    reg_type = params['reg_type']
    if reg_type=='1'
      current_user.create_default_company!
    end    
  end

  def update
    super
  end

end
```

However, my current_user is coming up nil.

```
undefined method `create_default_company!' for nil:NilClass
```

What can I use to reference the current_user immediately after super is called, which creates the user.

Params:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"E1urosfkmekwweklo/HZaEVrrmxQVKO9E=", "user"=>{"name"=>"", "email"=>"4@Gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up", "reg_type"=>"1"}
```

I am passing the parameter, using two links:

```
new_user_registration_path(reg_type: '0')
new_user_registration_path(reg_type: '1')
```

The action of the create depends on which link the user chooses.

Comment: you are calling the method on nil, obviously, because current_user is nil (how could it be any other way, if he is not created/signed_in yet?). You can check this param in after_create callback and then create default company

Comment: I was under the impression that after calling super on the create, the user is signed in and the user is created.  Is there a reference that shows the devise process?  Also, reg_type is not a field and not a method in my user model, how would I create an aftercreate callback to reference reg_type? I posted my params

Comment: what is reg_type, if it is not a field and not a method?

Comment: It's just a parameter in my form to tell me to process the create differently.

Comment: hm, not sure how to access registration param.. how is it defined?

Comment: Take a look at the params I posted and the links I posted to pass the extra parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this `reg_type` param in `after_create` callback and then create default company if it is equal to `'1'`.

Comment: I ended up putting the reg_type param in the User model, is there a way to check the params[] from the model without putting into the USER[]?

Answer (score 1):

If you open devise gem , you will find create method as

(devise-3.2.4)

```
 def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      yield resource if block_given?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end 
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end 
  end
```

you should first check which version of devise you are using then you can override that method in your controller.

In short using resource instead current_user may solve your problem, but it may generate inappropriate result as you will only assigning attributes (not saving) after rendering template.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the new user by passing a block to `super`:

```
def create
   super do |resource|
     if params['reg_type'] == "1"
        resource.create_default_company!
      end
    end
  end
```

This is explained (well, at least *mentioned*) in the [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) under "Configuring controllers".

The new user is accessible via the block parameter `resource`, although it might not be saved at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thank you for all the comments.  My solution was to use andrey deineko suggestion with a after_create call back.  I added an attr_accessor to reference the permission, which I added to the form as a hidden field.

I used..

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :reg_type
  after_create  :create_default_company!, if: :is_reg?

 def is_reg?
    @reg_type == '1'
  end
...

end
```

It seems to work well.  thank you for all the recommendations.